# How do I display a block on an edit form for particular content types?

Tags: 7, blocks, nodes

It's fairly simple to display a block on the node add form for a particular content type. Simply restrict visibility to a URL path like *node/add/article* and you're good to go.

I would like to know how to display a block on the edit form for a particular content type. For instance, when editing an article, the URL path is *node/NID/edit*.

Is there an easy way to display a block for edits of a given content type?

Comment: You need to use `php code` to implement this.

Comment: Do you have an example of a snippet I could put into the PHP code textarea to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `php code` in the `block Visibility settings` in admin section of block. You can follow below code.

```
$node = menu_get_object();

   if (isset($node) && $node->type == 'article' && arg(2) == 'edit') {

     return TRUE;
   }

   return FALSE
```

Another example:

```
$nid = arg(1);

   $node = node_load($nid);

   if (isset($node) && $node->type == 'article' && arg(2) == 'edit') {

     return TRUE;
   }

   return FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to display a block on an add and edit form for a particular content type via PHP code in the block configuration.

```
<?php
    $show_block = false;
    $content_type = 'article';
    $types = array($content_type);

    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
        $nid = arg(1);
        $node = node_load($nid);
        $type = $node->type;
        $show_block |= in_array($type, $types);
    } else if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(2) == $content_type) {
        $show_block = true;   
    }
    return $show_block;
?>
```